# Count cookie items

Tags: php, cookies

I show number of items in a `cookie` with:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['Bookmark'])) {
$sAds = explode(",",$_COOKIE['Bookmark']);
$countSAds = sizeof($sAds);
$savedAds = '<span>'.$countSAds.'</span>';
} else {
$savedAds = ''; 
}
```

And in `html`:

```
echo $savedAds; // output: <span>3</span>
```

Also sample data of cookie:

```
252,190,210
```

This is return `3`.

But if there is no bookmark (item) set in cookie, it show `1`, when there is nothing in this cookie, it return `0` so by `sizeof` it return `1` because it count number of `array`, how can I count cookie items if it is empty and should return `0`

**Example:**

sample data is nothing, I mean nothing in cookie, code return `<span>1</span>` but I want to show `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`!empty()`](https://php.net/empty) instead of `isset()` to check if there is something in the cookie:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['Bookmark'])) {
    $sAds = explode(",",$_COOKIE['Bookmark']);
    $countSAds = sizeof($sAds);
    $savedAds = '<span>'.$countSAds.'</span>';
} else {
    $savedAds = ''; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `empty` do this job. No I don't want show any `element` if it is empty. Thanks for the tip.